# Elasticsearch - Values less than -1 bytes are not supported querying nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm trying to query the nodes stats endpoint (_nodes/stats) and receive this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Values less than -1 bytes are not supported: -279601152b"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Values less than -1 bytes are not supported: -279601152b","suppressed":[{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"Failed to close the XContentBuilder","caused_by":{"type":"i_o_exception","reason":"Unclosed object or array found"}}]},"status":400}
```

Has anyone bumped into this before?  I'm similarly having trouble with setting up ILM rules where Kibana pushes this to the GUI when trying to setup rules:

```
Error loading node attribute information

400: Bad Request. [illegal_argument_exception] Values less than -1 bytes are not supported: -1306341376b
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is thrown from below code of Elasticsearch:

[Refer ES class code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/common/unit/ByteSizeValue.java#L67) if you want to have a complete look.

```
public ByteSizeValue(long size, ByteSizeUnit unit) {
        if (size < -1 || (size == -1 && unit != ByteSizeUnit.BYTES)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values less than -1 bytes are not supported: " + size + unit.getSuffix());
        }
        if (size > Long.MAX_VALUE / unit.toBytes(1)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Values greater than " + Long.MAX_VALUE + " bytes are not supported: " + size + unit.getSuffix());
        }
        this.size = size;
        this.unit = unit;
    }
```

Notice the first throw statement `Values less than -1 bytes are not supported:` and **your size of content seems to be very small 1306341376 byte**, as its less than -1 byte this exception is thrown.

**Solution:- Check the API content and make sure it passed this validation**

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Unfortunately, this wasn't the case.  I wound up needing to restart then upgrade the Elasticsearch node and it resolved itself.